# Screen Refresh jquery works on pc and not on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, linux, cookies

I have the following jquery script which simply allows a user to select a checkbox to turn the browser refresh on and off - and also specify the duration of the refresh in seconds. I save the details in cookies.

I've been trying to figure why it works on my pc and not on a Linux centOS server.

I'm missing something obvious but can't find a solution - can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
function saveValue(){
    Cookies.set("refreshScreen", $('#refreshScreen').is(':checked'));
    Cookies.set("seconds", $('#seconds').val() ? $('#seconds').val() : 0);

    setReload();
}

$(document).ready(function (){
    setReload();
});

function setReload(){
    val = Cookies.get("refreshScreen")
    if(val=='true')
        chk = true;
    else
        chk = false;

    seconds = Number (Cookies.get("seconds") ? Cookies.get("seconds") : 30 );

    $('#refreshScreen').attr('checked',chk);
    $('#seconds').val(seconds);

    if(chk){
        setTimeout(function () { location.reload(1); } , seconds*1000);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you see if you do `console.log(val)` and `console.log(seconds)` in `setReload`?

Comment: I get:
true
-and- input#secondsaccept: ""accessKey: ""align: ""alt: ""

Comment: when I uncheck I get false and input#secondsaccept: ""accessKey: ""align: ""alt: ""

Comment: That value for `seconds` is the clue, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variables as local variables. The problem is that you have an element with `id="seconds"`, and that's being used as the value of the global variable `seconds`.

```
function setReload(){
    var val = Cookies.get("refreshScreen") == 'true'

    var seconds = Number (Cookies.get("seconds") ? Cookies.get("seconds") : 30 );

    $('#refreshScreen').attr('checked',chk);
    $('#seconds').val(seconds);

    if(chk){
        setTimeout(function () { location.reload(1); } , seconds*1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure here but doesn't it get converted to string when putting to cookies..?

Comment: Check the documentation of the `Cookies` library you're using. I suspect it saves it as JSON, and parses it when it reads the cookie.

Comment: Whether I use a quote or boolean the result is the same. The problem on the server is whether the checkbox is on or off, it keeps refreshing; it also seems to ignore the seconds and refreshes at around 10 seconds.

Comment: Are you sure the `Cookies` library is being loaded correctly? Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Cookies load ok - I've checked the paths and the code - there's no errors at all on the javascript console...

Comment: The library is as follows if it helps:
/*!
 * Javascript Cookie v1.5.1
 * https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie
 *
 * Copyright 2006, 2014 Klaus Hartl
 * Released under the MIT license
 */

Comment: OK, it looks like my answer is wrong. It stores as JSON, but returns the JSON string unless you use `Cookies.getJSON`.

Comment: It seems better now as it's recognising the variables and their contents and they change as the input is changed - but still it refreshes even if it is checked or unchecked:
false   index.php?Page=Schedule&A=1:327 
20

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It's getting a 404 error for the js-cookies URL. You can't use github as a `src`.